# Azure API Management: Replace querystring parameter name

Tags: url-rewriting, azure-api-management

New to APIM. Trying to change the exposed querystring parameter name (not the value) with a different name that the backend api expects

For example, APIM endpoint expects /v1/Customer?CustomerId=123

I think I need to use rewrite-url policy on the inbound section?

To change it to this: /v1/Customer?ExternalCustomerId=123

---

Was trying this, doesn't work

```
<set-query-parameter name="ExternalCustomerId" exists-action="append">
        <value>@(Context.Request.QueryString["CustomerId"])</value>
    </set-query-parameter>
```

Error: The name 'Context' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 6):

This has changed as of september 2019. now use the following:

```
<set-query-parameter name="ExternalCustomerId" exists-action="append">
    <value>@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("CustomerId"))</value>
</set-query-parameter>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try lower case "context". Plus QueryString is a IReadOnlyDictionary as described here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ContextVariables, but there is a handy overload:

```
<set-query-parameter name="ExternalCustomerId" exists-action="append">
    <value>@(context.Request.QueryString.GetValueOrDefault("CustomerId"))</value>
</set-query-parameter>
```